# Virtual Folder accessible from IIS, but not from web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've been trying for a while to reduce what I'm trying to do to its simplest, working form.

At this point, my setup consists of:

- Clean Windows 10 install.
- Clean IIS 10 install.
- In IIS, I added a Virtual Directory aliased as "dddd" pointing to folder "d:\myfiles\" (which is outside the root web folder).
- In IIS, when I right click on "dddd" > Explore: Windows Explorer comes up with my list of files just fine.
- In IIS, however, when I right click on "dddd" > click "Manage Virtual Directory" > Browse > I get "Access is denied".

Not too surprising at this point; probably permissions related.  So I start to fiddle with NTFS permissions.

Before I change anything, I notice that this folder has the System account listed with full control, along with MY account also with Full Control (and also MY account as the owner).

I'll start by adding the Network Service account with (default) Permissions as Read & Execute, List Folder Content and Read permissions; however, no luck.

I'll then add the IIS_IUSRS account; with the same default permissions; still getting access denied.

At this point I don't want to go any further because my - surely limited - understanding of such things - tells me this should work.

Shouldn't it?

The why isn't it?

Or we can turn this around the other way and ask: What's the minimum permission(s) needed on a (virtual) folder sitting outside the Root IIS folder so that you can list its content by clicking a link on a practically naked HTML file on a practically clean Windows + IIS install?

Thank you,

Flood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding permissions for `IIS_IUSRS` was correct but not necessary for  `Network Service`, as long as you don't use it as the identity for the application pool.

At this point you have two options to make this work.

1. Adding permissions for `iusr` to  "d:\myfiles\"

or

2. Change the `Anonymous Authentication Credentials` for your site.

In IIS Manager select your site, double-click the `Authentication` icon and select `Anonymous Authentication`, on the right side click `Edit...` and then tick `Application Pool Identity`.

Now rather than `IUSR`, the application pool identity account is used to access the files and that account is automatically a member of `IIS_IUSRS` which already has permissions.

So to summaries, without making this change, both `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSRS` need read access.

I usually take `IUSR` out of the picture and just work with `IIS_IUSRS` or the actual application pool identities.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Can't wait to give this a try when I get home.

Comment: Peter, I applied your #2 option and it works, provided that I also turn on Directory Browsing.   Is the extra step of turning on Directory Browsing absolutely needed? It creates a webconfig file in the "d\myfiles\" folder.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because the IIS_IUSRS group that I've added to the NTFS permissions for that folder already has "List folder content".  Thank you.

Comment: @Flood - If you want users to browse / list content of that folder, you need to enable `Directory Browsing` this is different from `List folder content`, IIS vs. Windows OS, you need both.

Comment: You have answered my question and provided an explanation to boot.  How do I mark this as answered/resolved/etc?  Thank you.

Comment: @flood - There should be a check mark icon on the left of my answer. Clicking this accepts the answer. You may also click on an up arrow above it to mark it as valuable.